# How do you get the sportsmanship badge?

Tags: support, badges

What exactly means upvoting (100) *"competing answers"*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A competing answer, in this context, is any answer made by another user on a question where you already have an answer with a score of one or more. Note that only votes made after this criteria is met count (so if you upvote then post, it doesn't count).

---

As per the [List of Badges on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258):

> #### Sportsmanship
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Cast 100 upvotes on competing answers
>
>   - If you answer a question and earn a score of at least one, all other
>       answers to that question are
>       considered "competing answers"
>   - Upvotes you cast before you post your own answer do not count
>   - Deleted posts do not count
>   - Deleted/undone votes do not count
> - Originally proposed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/1215#1215)
>     in June 2009; implemented October
>     2010.
> - Sources: [badge announcement blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/),
>     [Jarrod's
>     explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68137/voting-for-competing-answers-sportsmanship-badge/68156#68156)

Comment: You know what's weirder? I searched for "sportsmanship" both in here and google, but both resulted with ZERO. I was expecting to see something, and I'm surprised that list of badges even exists out of the searching reach.